# Refresh desktop - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to refresh desktop, tried this,

```
Private Declare Function SHChangeNotify Lib "Shell32.dll" (ByVal wEventID As Long,
ByVal uFlags As Long, ByVal dwItem1 As Long, ByVal dwItem2 As Long) As Long

call SHChangeNotify(&H8000000&, &H0, vbNullString, vbNullString)
```

But it gives me error

[image]

What is the correct way to refresh desktop ?

Comment: that PInvoke doesnt seem correct for .NET.  see [SHChangeNotify](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHChangeNotify.html)

Comment: Is that redacted code? the call need to be in a sub/routine

Comment: Shell32.dll runs in win8. Does it run in xp and win7 ?

Comment: he is saying the `Call....` code needs to be in something like a sub or function, it cant just be hanging out there where declarations go

Answer (score 1):

You need to call **SHCangeNotify(&H8000000, &H0, Nothing, Nothing)** from within a method for example:

```
Public Class example

    Private Declare Function SHChangeNotify Lib "Shell32.dll" (ByVal wEventID As Long, _
                                                               ByVal uFlags As Long, _
                                                               ByVal dwitem1 As Long, _
                                                               ByVal deitem2 As Long) As Long

    Private Sub refreshWindow()

    SHCangeNotify(SHChangeNotify(&H8000000, &H0, Nothing, Nothing)

    End Sub

End Class
```